# Magick.Net Image FileSize is always Zero

Tags: c#, image-resizing, magick.net

I am working on requirement where during upload image from user on ASP.net form, I need to check if user provided image is greater than 500kb then I don't need to reduce the size of the image if it is above the size then reduce the size of the image but when I tried to use FileSize property it always show 0 value. I am using below code.

```
using (MagickImageCollection collection = new MagickImageCollection(txtInput.Text))
{
    collection.Coalesce();

    foreach (MagickImage image in collection)
    {
        if (image.FileSize >= 500)
        {
            image.Quality = 50;
            image.Sample(image.Width / 2, image.Height / 2);
        }
    }
    collection.Write(txtOutput.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting `0` for the file size because the frames of the image are not aware of the size of the complete image. I am the author of this library and decided to remove the FileSize property to avoid the confusion. The property has been removed in Magick.NET 7.3.0.0. The standard `System.IO` library should be sufficient to get the file size of an image.